# Max Connections Maria DB

Tags: mysql, mariadb, configuration, mariadb-10.1

Every time I reboot Mariadb places me the max_connections in 151 and in the my.cnf I have it with 300. Why does this happen?

Comment: Then wrong config file or not in `[mysqld]` section.  151 is usually plenty; why do you think you need more?  Is this a web site?  Driven by Apache?  nginx?  Tomcat?

Answer (score 5):

This depend if you set `max_connections` under the correct section inside `my.cnf`. what do you need to check(with examples)

1. go to MySQL Directory `cd /opt/mysql`
2. edit `my.cnf` using any text editor `sudo vi my.cnf`
3. search for `[mysqld]`
4. add the following lines directly under it `max_connections=300`
5. save and quit
6. restart the services.

Don't want a downtime?

1. connect to MySQL using root user `mysql -u root -p`
2. `SET GLOBAL max_connections=300;`
3. `quit`

Comment: I will check if it is below that directive

Comment: Just to be clear, the default location for my.cnf is `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` typically

Comment: For mariadb it's `/etc/mysql/mariadb.cnf.d/50-servers.cnf`

Answer (score 0):

What OS are you on?

If you are on Windows you can do this:

```
C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin>mysqld --verbose --help | findstr /i ini
```

Part of the output on my system is:

```
C:\WINDOWS\my.ini C:\WINDOWS\my.cnf C:\my.ini C:\my.cnf C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\my.ini C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\my.cnf
```

Which are ALL the possible location  this setting can be at 151, and not at 300.